# Load page in facebook app via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, facebook

I have created a facebook app which I'm using as a Page Tab. I'm using the PHP SDK and Javascript SDK, and have authenticated and set it up perfectly to display the dialogs and then my page within the tab iframe.

I would now like to load other pages of my site asynchronously, however I can not access the users data (name, etc.) on the asynchronously loaded pages. How do I pass the authentication and variables to the ajax loaded pages?

**(EDIT) Solution:**

The PHP SDK creates a session automatically to use amongst pages loaded with ajax (or anywhere). You just have to call your authentication routine on each page loaded with ajax in order to access the data (using a php include is best).

I load pages into a div using a simple jquery load:

```
$('div#page').load('your-page.php');
```

And this is the routine I run on each php page:

```
<?php
    //facebook application configuration
    $fbconfig['appid' ] = "YOUR APP ID";
    $fbconfig['secret'] = "YOUR APP SECRET";

    $fbconfig['baseUrl']    =   "SOURCE FILES BASE URL";
    $fbconfig['appBaseUrl'] =   "APP BASE URL";

    /* 
     * If user first time authenticated the application facebook
     * redirects user to baseUrl, so I checked if any code passed
     * then redirect him to the application url 
     */
    if (isset($_GET['code'])){
        header("Location: " . $fbconfig['appBaseUrl']);
        exit;
    }

    //
    if (isset($_GET['request_ids'])){
        //user comes from invitation
        //track them if you need
    }

    $user =   null; //facebook user uid
    try{
        include_once "facebook.php";
    }
    catch(Exception $o){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($o);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    // Create our Application instance.
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
      'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
      'cookie' => true,
    ));

    //Facebook Authentication part
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    // We may or may not have this data based 
    // on whether the user is logged in.
    // If we have a $user id here, it means we know 
    // the user is logged into
    // Facebook, but we don’t know if the access token is valid. An access
    // token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array(
                'scope' => 'email,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location,user_work_history,user_about_me,user_hometown'
            )
    );

    if ($user) {
      try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        //you should use error_log($e); instead of printing the info on browser
        d($e);  // d is a debug function defined at the end of this file
        $user = null;
      }
    }

    if (!$user) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
        exit;
    }

    //get user basic description
    $userInfo = $facebook->api("/$user");

    function d($d){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($d);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends of how you do your request, but you can save the data in a $_SESSION variable, like $_SESSION['userData'] = $facebook->api('/me'); and call it on every pages.